# How to Check Whether an Angular $q promise Is Resolved

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I understand that typically one would just attach continuation code with a `then()` call and chain behaviour when using promises.

However, I want to kick off a promise-wrapped asynchronous call and then separately kick off a 3-second `$timeout()` so I can take a UI action, ONLY IF the original promise has not yet completed.  (I anticipate that this would only happen on slow connections, mobile devices on 3G, etc.)

Given a promise, can I check whether it's complete or not without blocking or waiting?

Comment: I opened an issue on this in angular and got a helpful response https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8307#issuecomment-49903373

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039771/q-js-is-it-possible-to-know-if-a-promise-has-resolved-rejected-or-not

Answer (score 48):

I guess this was added in a recent version of Angular but there seems to be now an $$state object on the promise:

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 console.log(deferred.promise.$$state.status); // 0
 deferred.resolve();
 console.log(deferred.promise.$$state.status); //1
```

As noted in the comments this is not recommended as it might break when upgrading your Angular version.

Comment: Angular docs say `$$...` properties shouldn't be used. Might be risky when upgrading to newer versions of Angular...

Comment: Too bad Angular provides its private variables on a silver platter. :(

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039771/q-js-is-it-possible-to-know-if-a-promise-has-resolved-rejected-or-not

Comment: But but... Angular didn't implement the `inspect` function. So no juice for us Angular devs. Promise prototype simply doesn't have it.

Answer (score 37):

I think your best option as is, (without modifying the Angular source and submitting a pull request) is to keep a local flag for if the promise has been resolved.  Reset it every time you setup the promise you're interested in and mark it as complete in the `then()` for the original promise. In the `$timeout` `then()` check the flag to know if the original promise has resolved yet or not.

Something like this:

```
var promiseCompleted = false;
promise.then(function(){promiseCompleted=true;})
$timeout(...).then(function(){if(!promiseCompleted)doStuff()})
```

Kris Kowal's implementation includes other methods for checking the state of the promise but it appears Angular's implementation of `$q` unfortunately doesn't include these.

Comment: It would be better to use .finally() here.
The code provided above will only mark the promiseCompleted flag to true if it was successfully resolved.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't seem to be possible, as @shaunhusain already mentioned. But maybe it's not necessary:

```js
// shows stuff from 3s ahead to promise completetion, 
// or does and undoes it in one step if promise completes before
$q.all(promise, $timeout(doStuff, 3000)).then(undoStuff);
```

or maybe better:

```js
var tooSlow = $timeout(doStuff, 3000);
promise.always(tooSlow.cancel);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem where I need to check if a promise has returned. Because AngularJS's `$watch` function will register a change while rendering the page even if both new and old values are undefined, I have to check to see if there is any data worth storing in my external model.

It is definitely a hack but I do this:

```
$scope.$watch('userSelection', function() {
  if(promiseObject.hasOwnProperty("$$v"){
    userExportableState.selection = $scope.userSelection;
  }
};
```

I know that `$$v` is an internal variable used by AngularJS, but it has been quite reliable as an indicator of a resolved promise for us. Who knows what will happen when we upgrade to AngularJS 1.2 :-/  I don't see any mention of improvements to `$q` in the 1.2 docs but perhaps someone will write a replacement service with a better feature set closer to Q.

Comment: Thanks, but there are better options than using "private" members.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact scenario but it is more typical to put a timeout in place immediately after making the asynchronous call (and generating the promise).

Providing the `setTimeout()` statement is in the same event thread as the asynchronous call, you needn't worry about the possibility of a race effect. As javascript is strictly single threaded, the promise's `.then()` callbacks are guaranteed to fire in a later event thread.