# q.js : Is it possible to know if a promise has resolved/rejected or not

Tags: promise, q

In my scenario I return a promise when I'm making a request.

In the end I resolve/reject the deferred obj.

I want to reuse the promise if it hasn't been resolved/rejected.

Any info would be useful.

Comment: It's good that you've found your answer but "reuse"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer by looking into q.js source.

```
deferred.promise.inspect().state
```

This will return the state of the promise.

```
returns "fulfilled" if it was resolved or fulfilled
returns "rejected" if it was rejected
returns "pending" if it hasn't been resolved or rejected
```

Comment: I get promise.inspect is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the state inspection methods which are less verbose.  And calling a method is always better than checking `===` with state.  If there is a typo with a method you will get an error immediately.  With `===` a typo will return `false` which could be a bug.  From the Q API reference,

`promise.isFulfilled()`

Returns whether a given promise is in the fulfilled state. When the static
version is used on non-promises, the result is always `true`.

`promise.isRejected()`

Returns whether a given promise is in the rejected state. When the static
version is used on non-promises, the result is always `false`.

`promise.isPending()`

Returns whether a given promise is in the pending state. When the static version
is used on non-promises, the result is always `false`.